# C Floating Point Division Result Rounded to Zero

Tags: c, floating-point, division

Why does this expression give me an output of zero?

```
float x = ((1000)/(24 * 60 * 60));
```

Breaking this into two parts, gives the correct result:

```
float x = (1000);
x /= (24 * 60 * 60);
```

Comment: That is not floating point, your constants are integers.

Comment: Well, what does this do? 1) declare a variable `x` of type `float`. 2) Calculate `24*60*60` which is 86400. 3) Calculate 1000/86400 which is 0. 4) Store 0 in `x`.

Comment: @immibis This comment is clear enough to be an answer. At least, it's better than all answers now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement

```
float x = ((1000)/(24 * 60 * 60));
```

does the following:

1. Declares a variable `x` of type `float`.
2. Evaluates `((1000)/(24 * 60 * 60))`.

   1. Evaluates `24*60*60` which is 86400.
   2. Evaluates `1000/86400` which is 0.
3. Assigns the result of that (which is 0) to `x`.

In the second step, `((1000)/(24 * 60 * 60))` is zero - the division is integer division, because both operands are integers. The fact that the result gets assigned to a floating point variable later makes no difference.

The simplest fix is to make sure either side of the division is a floating-point number, so it will use floating-point division. For example, you could change `1000` to `1000.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer, it will give you the correct output

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    float x = (float)1000/(24 * 60 * 60);
    printf("%f",x);
    return 0;
}
```

Output: 0.011574
Output can also be seen: http://ideone.com/6bMp9r

Comment: `1000f` is better than `(float)1000`